# Select and count uniqe value where gender = X

Tags: sql, join, count, oledb, distinct

I have a  sql query :

```
SELECT t1.Nev, 
       Count(t2.Datum) AS Edzes_szam 
FROM   Adatok t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Kod, 
                                   Datum 
                   FROM   Jelenlet 
                   WHERE  Datum LIKE '" + dtm_year_hkszpp_ym + "%') t2 
               ON t1.Azon_sima = t2.Kod 
GROUP  BY t1.Nev
```

I would like to ask your help to change it for only  `gender='X'` have to be counted.

This query count for a name how many times was it logged in a selected month.
I would like to make a filter for gender. How and where i have to take this `where gender = 'X'`.

I'm using MSOLEDB.

Comment: It depends on which table do you have gender column

Comment: Have you tried putting your WHERE clause right before the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: When asking a question, use qualified column names for all the columns in the query (that is, include the table alias).  We don't know where the columns are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its too simple. If you have gender column in Adatok table then, Try it:-

```
SELECT t1.Nev, 
   Count(t2.Datum) AS Edzes_szam 
FROM   Adatok t1 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Kod, 
                               Datum 
               FROM   Jelenlet 
               WHERE  Datum LIKE '" + dtm_year_hkszpp_ym + "%') t2 
           ON t1.Azon_sima = t2.Kod 
WHERE t1.gender = 'X'
GROUP  BY t1.Nev
```

Otherwise, Try this:-

```
SELECT t1.Nev, 
   Count(t2.Datum) AS Edzes_szam 
FROM   Adatok t1 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Kod, 
                               Datum 
               FROM   Jelenlet 
               WHERE  Datum LIKE '" + dtm_year_hkszpp_ym + "%'
               AND gender = 'X') t2 
           ON t1.Azon_sima = t2.Kod 

GROUP  BY t1.Nev
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery for what you are doing:

```
SELECT A.Nev, Count(DISTINCT J.Datum) AS Edzes_szam 
FROM Adatok a INNER JOIN
     Jelenlet j
     ON A.Azon_sima = j.Kod AND
        j.Datum LIKE '" + dtm_year_hkszpp_ym + "%'
GROUP BY a.Nev ;
```

With this structure, you can just add `WHERE gender = <whatever>` before the `GROUP BY`.

Your code sort of suggests that you are using `LIKE` for dates.  This is not recommended in any database.  All have built-in date and time functions that are better than `LIKE`.